# Interchanging position in multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

How can i interchange the position of two elements in a multidimensional array?

Suppose i have an array : `int Array[][]`

```
Array={{1,2,3},{2,0,5},{-9,6,5}};
```

and a method like `void interchange(position1,position2,newposition1,newposition2)`

and  statement like `interchange(1,1,3,1)`

so that i get this array: `{-9,2,3},{2,0,5},{1,6,5}` with minimum copying of variables/statements in body.

**Edit:**
**I knew the basic approach, but was wishing someone could tell a method related to pointers. I said "with minimum copying of variables/statements in body." to ask if there was a shorter method than assignment**

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? Why aren't you satisfied with what you tried?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Its fairly straight forward . I don't understand what problems you are facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudocode

```
function interchange(position1,position2,newposition1,newposition2) {
    // store the value at (position1,position2)
    var temp = Array[position1][position2]

    // put in (position1,position2) the value at (newposition1,newposition2)
    Array[position1][position2] = Array[newposition1][newposition2]

    // put in (newposition1,newposition2) the value previously stored
    Array[newposition1][newposition2] = temp
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that there could be use of something like pointers. But I have heard Java has no pointers.

Comment: Every single `Object` instance is actually a pointer. One could say that Java **only** has pointers (apart from primitive types).

Answer (score 2):

> plus tried `Array[1][1]=Array[3][1]`

This won't work because you would lose a value of `[1][1]`, so take a look at [Swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_%28computer_science%29)

> The simplest and probably most widely used method to swap two variables is to use a third temporary variable:

pseudocode, not Java:

```
define swap (x, y)
    temp := x
    x := y
    y := temp
```

Comment: @Aditya, it would be overwritten without prior keeping it.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int[][] swap(int[][] target, int xFrom, int yFrom, int xTo, int yTo){
  int temp = target[xTo][yTo];
  target[xTo][xTo] = target[xFrom][yFrom];
  target[xFrom][yFrom] = temp;
  return target;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question's a little vague, but hopefully this is what you're looking for?

```
public int[][] swap(int[][] arr, int ind1, int subind1, int ind2, int subind2) {
    int arg1 = arr[ind1][subind1];
    arr[ind1][subind1] = arr[ind2][subind2];
    arr[ind2][subind2] = arg1;
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: This is not what he wants. He wants to swap elements not the entire row.